# Calculus mapping and proof

Tags: calculus, functions

Not sure where to go with this question, any help would be appreciated.

**QUESTION**
Let X:={1,2}. Find a map f:X→X and subsets A and B of X such that f(A∩B)≠ f(A)∩f(B).

**ATTEMPT**
I've proven that f(AnB)= f(A)nf(B) if f is injective, but I'm not sure if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try $A=\{1\}$, $B=\{2\}$, $f(1)=f(2)=1$.

Then $f(A\cap B)=f(\emptyset)=\emptyset$ but $f(A)\cap f(B)=\{1\}$.

You see that this $f$ is not injective, so your proof does help to find this answer.